# Small issue with Palindrome program

Tags: python, palindrome

I've been working on this Palindrome program and am really close to completing it.Close to the point that it's driving me a bit crazy haha.
The program is supposed to check each 'phrase' to determine if it is a Palindrome or not and return a lowercase version with white space and punctuation removed if it is in fact a Palindrome. Otherwise, if not, it's supposed to return None.
I'm just having an issue with bringing my test data into the function. I can't seem to think of the correct way of dealing with it. It's probably pretty simple...Any ideas?
Thanks!

```py
import string

def reverse(word):
    newword = ''
    letterflag = -1
    for numoletter in word:
        newword += word[letterflag]
        letterflag -= 1
    return newword


def Palindromize(phrase):
    for punct in string.punctuation:
        phrase= phrase.replace(punct,'')
        phrase = str(phrase.lower())

    firstindex = 0
    secondindex = len(phrase) - 1
    flag = 0
    while firstindex != secondindex and firstindex < secondindex:
        char1 = phrase[firstindex]
        char2 = phrase[secondindex]
        if char1 == char2:
            flag += 1
        else:
            break
        firstindex += 1
        secondindex -= 1
    if flag == len(phrase) // (2):
        print phrase.strip()
    else:
        print None

def Main():
    data = ['Murder for a jar of red rum',12321, 'nope', 'abcbA', 3443, 'what',
    'Never odd or even', 'Rats live on no evil star']
    for word in data:
        word == word.split()
        Palindromize(word)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: `int`'s don't have `split` method. Try changing them into strings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this line is causing the problems.

```
for word in data:
    word == word.split() # This line.
    Palindromize(word)
```

You're testing for equality here, rather than reassigning the variable `word` which can be done using `word = word.split()`. `word` then becomes a list, and you might want to iterate over the list using

```
for elem in word:
    Palindromize(elem)
```

Also, you seem to be calling the `split` method on `int`, which is not possible, try converting them to strings.

Also, why do you convert the phrase to lower case in the for loop, just doing it once will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

At the "core" of your program, you could do much better in Python, using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) for example. Here is a quick demonstration:

```
>>> phrase = 'Murder for a jar of red rum!'

>>> normalized = filter(str.isalnum, phrase.lower())
>>> normalized
'murderforajarofredrum'

>>> reversed = normalized[-1::-1]
>>> reversed
'murderforajarofredrum'

# Test is it is a palindrome
>>> reversed == normalized
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you go bananas, let's rethink the problem:

1. You have already pointed out that Palindromes only make sense in strings without punctuation, whitespace, or mixed case. Thus, you need to convert your input string, either by removing the unwanted characters or by picking the allowed ones. For the latter, one can imagine:

> import string
>
> clean_data = [ch for ch in original_data if ch in string.ascii_letters]
>
> clean_data = ''.join(clean_data).lower()

1. Having the cleaned version of the input, one might consider the third parameter in slicing of strings, particularly when it's -1 ;)

Does a comparison like

```
if clean_data[::-1] == clean_data:
    ....
```

ring a bell?

Answer (score 0):

One of  the primary errors that i spotted is here:

```
for word in data:
    word==word.split()
```

Here, there are two mistakes:
   1. Double equals make no point here.
   2. If you wish to split the contents of each iteration of data, then doing like this doesn't change the original list, since you are modifying the duplicate set called `word`. To achieve your list, do:

```
for i in range(data):   
      data[i]=data[i].split()
```

This may clear your errors